# Joining with both historical and streaming data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking to implement a streaming search/filtering system in Dataflow. The system itself is quite complex, so I'll use a simplified example to describe my question.

Say I want to allow users of my system to set up an alert for news articles, matching any article that contains a specified keyword. What's relevant to my question is that when an alert is added to the system it needs to go back and match *all* previous articles containing that keyword. It also needs to start matching against any new articles, of course.

My idea is to join a stream of articles with a stream of alerts, checking each article against each alert.

My question is this: what would be a good way to have an archive of past articles that can be checked against *new* alerts, and is there a way to avoid having too much complexity and special casing? Ideally, I'd just keep all the articles in a pcollection with a global window and a trigger that emits all new elements and join with a stream of alerts. Is this feasible? And how do I ensure that I don't lose the articles if there's a problem with my job?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, every time a new article arrives, you want to scan all existing alerts and find ones that match; and every time a new alert arrives, likewise, you want to scan all existing articles and find ones that match.

I suppose you have some efficient way of locating matching articles for an alert and matching alerts for an article, rather than scanning the whole database, but if not (e.g. if the database is small), that's fine too.

One option is a system like this:

- When a new article is added, 1) write it to an indexed storage system (e.g. Bigtable, or Elasticsearch, or a database, or something like that) 2) emit a "new article" event to a PubSub topic
- When a new alert is added, do the converse: also write to an indexed storage system and emit an event
- Have a pipeline listening to the events on both pubsub topics. When getting a "new article" event, it scans the alerts database for matching alerts (using whatever indexing available). When getting a "new alert" event, for matching articles.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It does, but I would like to do this in Dataflow, including keeping the state. Also, I need to be able to handle archived data. So I'm looking for a way to implement this using Dataflow constructs.

Comment: Also: the set of alerts will be small, only a handful probably, but the set of articles will be massive, on the order of hundreds of millions. I don't mind a delay when a new alert is added, so processing every single `(article, segment)` combination whenever there's a new segment is OK, as long as Dataflow can scale to that.

Comment: I see. I would still suggest to use the approach in my answer: Dataflow can maintain decent amounts of state, but it is not a storage system, so I would not recommend to try using it as such for hundreds of millions of articles.

Comment: OK – I'll try to look into alternatives then. Thanks!